# Cleaning inside of headlamp housing

Tags: headlight, cleaning, maruti

my family owns a 2009 Maruti Suzuki Alto. Sometime back the RHS lamp exploded inside the housing, since then the housing became hazy, although the light output does not seems to be affected much, I want to know of it is possible clean the inside just so that both headlamps matches. I have tried vacuuming after removing the housing from the body and all the big glass bits were removed, but a small layer of glass dust still remains. If you can tell me how to remove this it would be very helpful. 
PS already thought of stuffing a microfibre cloth inside, but did not wanted to risk it as it may cause scratches in the reflector. The below posted image is for reference only 
[image: for reference only]

Answer (score 0):

I've had success in the past by removing a complete headlight assembly and warming it in a very low temperature oven to soften the adhesive that bonds the outer lens to the unit.  It then become possible to carefully and gently prise the lens away from the unit allowing access to clean the inside of the reflector.

Comment: I am not very confident about disassembling the housing as I have never done it before, can you suggest any other method? @Steve Matthews

Comment: You could try it with the headlight assembly insitu be removing all the of bulbs and blasting an airline into the bulb holes.